# JSON to java object returing LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have below `json` string :-

```
{"name":"Test","sortlist":[],"filterlist":[{"fieldname":"regions_id","operator":"equals","value":{"id":1,"code":"HIGH","description":"HIGH Region","comment":"High Region","active":true}}]}
```

and Java class as below :-

```
@JsonSerialize
@JsonDeserialize
public class ItemFilter implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private List<FieldFilter> filterlist = new ArrayList<FieldFilter>();

}

public class FieldFilter  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String fieldname;
    private String operator;
    private Object value;
}
```

and my convert method as below :-

```
public static ItemFilter convertItemFilter(String item) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            ItemFilter itemFilter = mapper.readValue(item, new TypeReference<ItemFilter>(){});
            return itemFilter;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

`ItemFilter` domain is getting converted correctly but  in `private Object value;` field i am getting `LinkedHashMap` i want to get an simple object and later i will type cast it.

Can someone please guide me how to escape `LinkedHashMap` and get an simple `Java` `Object` in variable?

i cant use hard coding Object type because its a generic pojo which can have any object type. hard coding will make this pojo very bigger and frontend also need to change for it. So that why i have used Object as data type.

Comment: That's a problem. If it does convert to Object type, then where will it save the values of `"id":1,"code":"HIGH","description":"HIGH Region","comment":"High Region","active":true`?

Since it cannot find any related field for id,code,... It converts it to a linkedhashmap and sets these values in that map.
As a work around, why don't you create a **setter for field value** and call a transformer API which transform's this LinkedHashmap into the object type that you want?

Answer (score -1):

The following class structure should return the JSON to "YourObject"

```
public class YourObject{
  private String name;
  private List<String> sortList;
  private List<Filter> filterList;

public static class Filter{
  private String fieldname;
  private String operator;
  private Value value;

}
public static class Value{
  private Integer id;
  private String code;
  private String description;
  private String comment;
  private Boolean active;
}
}
```

Then use the following to read it into the object:

```
YourObject itemFilter = mapper.readValue(item, YourObject.class);
```

Comment: i cant use this because its a generic pojo which can have any object type. hard coding object type cant be used.